# Is $\pi$ the radius of convergence of the taylor series of $f(z)=\frac{1}{1+e^z}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I'm having trouble with the following exercise:

> is it true that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of the function $$f(z)=\frac{1}{1+e^z}$$ centered at $z=0$ is $\pi$?

I tried to evaluate the taylor series combining the two identities: $$e^z=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{z^n}{n!}$$
$$\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n\geq0}z^n,|z|<1$$

but it got really messy very quickly and I wasn't able to conclude anything about the radius of convergence.

Given that this is a True/False type question, is it possible to conclude anything without actually evaluating the Taylor series? If so, how?

Comment: All you need to do is to determine the minimal pole of $f$. I suppose this is an exercise in complex analysis, to which you need to apply a theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed true. Look for the poles of $f(z)$. Quite clearly, they occur when $e^{z} = -1$. The smallest solutions - in terms of argument - to this equation are $\pm i \pi$.

Hence, we see the closest poles of $f$ to the center of the desired Taylor are at a distance of $\pi$ in the complex plane. A standard result shows the radius of convergence of a Taylor series is equal to the distance of the center of the expansion to the nearest singular point (in this case a pole) of the function we seek to represent.

Comment: the radius of convergence equals ( rather than $\le $) the distance to the singular set ( in this case, consisting of poles). For $\sqrt{1- z}$, $z=1$ is a singular point ( a branch point, not a pole). :-)  This is an important result of Cauchy, [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Radius_of_convergence_in_complex_analysis)

Answer (score 3):

The function is analytic in $\{z:|z|<\pi\}$ so the power series expansion is valid in this disk. The radius of convergence is determined by  the nearest pole to $0$ and the nearest pole in this case is $z=i\pi$ so the radius of convergence is indeed $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively the radius of convergence is the radius of the largest disk around $0$ that you can find in which $1/(1+e^z)$ is analytic, that's the distance to the closest points where $1 + e^z = 0$.  These points are $\pm i\pi$, so the radius of convergence is $\pi$.

Comment: Intuitively? It's a result you can prove!